# jquery mouse events not working on anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, onmouseover

I have an anchor tag and hovering which, I want my div to get displayed and should get hidden on mouseout. Just a typical jquery mouse events.

However, that doesn't seems to work. Could someone help me out on this. Check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SLLeL/

```
$(".contributor").on({

mouseover: function(e) {

populateContributorsInArray(this);
var mousex = e.pageX - LEFT; // Get X coordinates
var mousey = e.pageY - TOP; // Get Y coordinates
$('#myDiv').css({
    top : mousey,
    right : mousex
});

var ul_data = "";
for ( var i = 0; i < CONTRIBUTORS.length; i++) {
    ul_data = ul_data + "<li>" + CONTRIBUTORS[i] + "</li>";
}
$("#myDiv ul").html(ul_data);
$("#myDiv").stop().hide().slideToggle('fast');
$("#arrow-left").stop().hide().slideToggle('fast');

},

mouseout: function(){
    alert("hi");
//Basically hide the div
//      $("#contributors_div").stop().hide().slideToggle('fast');
//      $("#arrow-left").stop().hide().slideToggle('fast');
}
});
```

And the HTML

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <div id="arrow-left"></div>
    <ul></ul>
</div>

<a class="contributor" href="#">Hover Me</a>
```

Comment: where is `populateContributorsInArray` function... this function is missing in you jsfiddle

Comment: Error in var CONTRIBUTORS = {"abc", "def"}; in jsfiddle hover event working fine change it into var CONTRIBUTORS = ["abc", "def"];

Comment: `populateContributorsInArray` is basically a function which populates `CONTRIBUTORS` array by reading through JSON and then I loop over the array to put contributors in that `ul` tag inside the div which is to be displayed.

Comment: `CONTRIBUTORS` array is populated by splitting a comma separated String.  `CONTRIBUTORS = list.split(",");` something like this.

Answer (score 2):

you created an object instead of array.. so the error you had was `Unexpected token ,` check your console...

change

```
var CONTRIBUTORS = {"abc", "def"};
```

to array

```
var CONTRIBUTORS = ["abc", "def"];
```

and it should work..  though your fiddle is missing the `populateContributorsInArray` function which is called inside the mouseover method..

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/SLLeL/1/)

Comment: As i told above, `populateContributorsInArray` is basically a function which populates `CONTRIBUTORS` array by reading through JSON and then I loop over the array to put contributors in that `ul` tag inside the div which is to be displayed.

Comment: `CONTRIBUTORS` array is populated by splitting a comma separated String.  `CONTRIBUTORS = list.split(",");` something like this.

Comment: yes. I am not able to show the div.  Actually, i wanted this div to appear as tooltip but unable to do so.